# I can't create a doc or docx file in Android (Xamarin), with a writer permission. Only readonly

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying copy the local file and edit it. But when I copy file, the new file is create with readonly permission.

I try to create a new file in other folder, but the same thing happen.

My code:
(Copy local file)

```
//anexoPath (local file path)
//anexoPath (new file path)

System.IO.File.Copy(anexoPath, anexoPathSigned);
System.IO.File.SetAttributes(anexoPathSigned, FileAttributes.Normal);

System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(anexoPathSigned);
fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
```

(New file)

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(anexoPathSigned,
                               FileMode.Create,
                               FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                               FileShare.ReadWrite,
                               4096,
                               FileOptions.Asynchronous);


byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("FileStream Test");
fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
fs.Close();
```

Result in both cases:
[image]

**OBS: When I open the word and save a new file in the same path, work!!**

Anybody can help me?

Comment: I have posted an answer for your problem and you can get full sample solution on github: https://github.com/lemontreexf123/test1

Comment: Hey man! Thank you for your answer! I will go test today and return to you, if works!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I solved your problem by the following steps(You can get full solution on [github](https://github.com/lemontreexf123/test1) )

1  Add permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

2  Set the filepath using:

```
var exoFilepath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/test.txt";
```

3  Need Runtime Permission Checks if Apps that will run on Android 6.0 (API 23 level 23) or higher.

```
private void CheckWriteFliePermissions()
    {
        // Check if the Camera permission is already available.
        if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted
            || ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
        {

            // Write permission has not been granted
            RequestWriteFilePermissions();

        }
        else
        {
            // Wrie File permissions is already available
            Log.Info("MainActicity", "Write file permission has already been granted.");
            ProcessFiles();
        }
    }

    void RequestWriteFilePermissions()
    {
        Log.Info("MainActicity", "Write file permission has NOT been granted. Requesting permission.");

        if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage)
            || ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage))
        {
            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
            Log.Info("MainActicity", "Displaying Write file permission rationale to provide additional context.");

            Snackbar.Make(layout, "Write file permission is needed to write files.",
                Snackbar.LengthIndefinite).SetAction("OK", new Action<View>(delegate (View obj) {
                    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_READWRITE, 0);
                })).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            // Camera permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_READWRITE, 0);
        }
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        if (requestCode == 0)
        {
            // Received permission result for camera permission.
            Log.Info("MainActivity", "Received response for write file permission request.");

            // Check if the only required permission has been granted
            if (PermissionUtil.VerifyPermissions(grantResults))
            {
                // All required permissions have been granted, display contacts fragment.
                ProcessFiles();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Info("MainActivity", "Contacts permissions were NOT granted.");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    public void ProcessFiles()
    {

        var exoFilepath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/test.txt";
        Log.Debug("MainActivity", "exoFilepath"+ exoFilepath);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(exoFilepath,
                           FileMode.Create,
                           FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                           FileShare.ReadWrite,
                           4096,
                           FileOptions.Asynchronous);


        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("FileStream Test");
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        fs.Close();

    }
```